# concatenate files in one folder in perl use linux shell script

Tags: perl

In linux, to concatenate all files under a folder, you can do `file=FOLDER/*; cat $file > ONEFILE`, I also want to use this in my perl script so I coded like `system("file=$folder/*");
 system("cat \$file > $out");`

But it won't work when I run the perl program, the $out was assigned a file name as `my $out = "outfile";`. The outfile always keeps at 0 bit. What's wrong here.

Comment: I think I already know the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line sets the `$file` environment variable in a new shell process:

```
system "file=$folder/*";
```

The second line starts a new shell process with a new environment:

```
system "cat \$file > $out";
```

Since it's a new process, with a new environment, your previous `$file` variable is no longer set, so you are really running the following shell command:

```
cat  > $out
```

Do this instead:

```
system "cat '$folder/'* > '$out';
```

Note - I also added quotes, which will help if your paths may contain spaces.  However, it's still not safe against all forms of input, so don't pass any user input to that command without validating it first.

Answer (score 0):

What's about `exec` in Perl?

`perl -e 'exec "cat *.txt"'`